# Google Dataflow and Apache beam: why ValueProvider

Tags: python, google-cloud-dataflow, apache-beam

I'm pretty new to Dataflow and trying to build a template with Python.

This is the [document](https://cloud.google.com/dataflow/docs/guides/templates/creating-templates#python) that makes me confused.

Is there any reason that we use a ValueProvider?

I've found many official templates using just Python `argparse`.

When should I use which solution?

1. Create a subclass of `PipelineOptions` and use ValueProvider

```
@classmethod
def _add_argparse_args(cls, parser):
    parser.add_value_provider_argument(
        "--input", dest="input", required=True, help="Input for the pipeline",
    )
    ...
```

Or
2. Use `argparse` parsing arguments in `if __nam__ == "__main__"` block?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The reason to use `ValueProvider` through `PipelineOptions` instead of using `argparse` directly for arguments is to enable runtime parameters. Understanding how this is useful involves understanding the difference between runtime parameters and construction time parameters. As the [Dataflow Templates Overview](https://cloud.google.com/dataflow/docs/guides/templates/overview#templated-dataflow-jobs) states:

> If you use Dataflow templates, staging and execution are separate
> steps. This separation gives you additional flexibility to decide who
> can run jobs and where the jobs are run from.

When you create and stage your template, that's when regular arguments are evaluated. So if you use `argparse` directly, or you have some arguments in your `PipelineOptions` that use `add_argument`, those are specified when you first call your template code to construct and stage the job graph. So you will generally only run this once to stage the job, and then afterwards you can execute the job repeatedly.

Whenever you execute a job that's been staged, you are able to [specify additional runtime parameters](https://cloud.google.com/dataflow/docs/guides/templates/running-templates#custom-templates). Unlike the construction time parameters that were only specified once when constructing the pipeline, runtime parameters can be specified each time you run your staged job, and therefore can be changed far more often. However, transforms need to explicitly support runtime arguments as `ValueProviders` for this to be an option.

So to summarize, the decision of whether to use a `ValueProvider` or not depends on whether you need the argument when constructing your graph, or when running your pipeline. Construction time arguments are mainly for arguments that affect graph construction, or are expected to stay the same through multiple runs of a job. Arguments that are likely to change each time you run a job, such as input files, should be runtime arguments (i.e. `ValueProviders`) assuming the transforms you're using support it.