# How to set the value of a Java Beam `ValueProvider` and why is it needed at all?

Tags: google-cloud-dataflow, apache-beam

In this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62948039/google-dataflow-and-apache-beam-why-valueprovider) and in [GCP docs](https://cloud.google.com/dataflow/docs/guides/templates/creating-templates#valueprovider) it is explained that `ValueProvider` can make values available at the pipeline execution time (=Runtime), instead of pipeline construction time.

In particular, I see this example:

```
  public interface SumIntOptions extends PipelineOptions {
      // New runtime parameter, specified by the --int
      // option at runtime.
      ValueProvider<Integer> getInt();
      void setInt(ValueProvider<Integer> value);
  }

  class MySumFn extends DoFn<Integer, Integer> {
      ValueProvider<Integer> mySumInteger;

      MySumFn(ValueProvider<Integer> sumInt) {
          // Store the value provider
          this.mySumInteger = sumInt;
      }

      @ProcessElement
      public void processElement(ProcessContext c) {
         // Get the value of the value provider and add it to
         // the element's value.
         c.output(c.element() + mySumInteger.get());
      }
  }
```

But, this provides little to no benefit, because I could do the same without any `ValueProvider`, by simply storing the `Serializable` int in `MySymFn` instead:

```
  public interface SumIntOptions extends PipelineOptions {
      // New runtime parameter, specified by the --int
      // option at runtime.
      int getInt();
      void setInt(int value);
  }

  class MySumFn extends DoFn<Integer, Integer> {
      // This will serialize
      private final int sumInt;

      MySumFn(int sumInt) {
          // Store the value
          this.sumInt = sumInt;
      }

      @ProcessElement
      public void processElement(ProcessContext c) {
         // Get the value
         c.output(c.element() + sumInt);
      }
  }
```

I can even access the `SumIntOptions` directly inside my `DoFn`:

```
      @ProcessElement
      public void processElement(ProcessContext c) {
         // Get the value
         int sumInt = c.getPipelineOptions().as(SumIntOptions.class).getInt();
         c.output(c.element() + sumInt);
      }
```

So, it is really not clear what purpose does `ValueProvider` serve (other than maybe some internal Beam needs).

It is also not clear if the value of a `ValueProvider` can be set in other ways, other than essentially static `Options` and `StaticValueProvider`. I found no example of this. Is there a way to set the value at DAG Runtime / inside a custom `DoFn`?